# Create a recipe for zabbix configuration

Tags: chef-infra

I need your help in creating a recipe for managing a Zabbix configuration file.

The configuration file should remain same on all servers except the hostname parameter in the configuration file.

The configuration should contain the following parameter's, but the hostname parameter should be the hostname of the machine where the agent is installed. Rest all parameter can be unique in all the servers.

Please advise.

Template:

```
Server=abc@xyz.net
ServerActive=abc@xyz.net
StartAgents=5
DebugLevel=3
PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log
LogFileSize=0
Timeout=3
Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d
Hostname=<%= node['hostname'] %>'
```

Recipe:

```
template '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf' do
source 'mytest.erb'
owner 'root'
group 'root'
mode '755'
end
```

Comment: You have a superfluous `'` at the end of the `Hostname` line. But that shouldn't be a problem for Chef, only for Zabbix.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the node's fully-qualified domain name via the [automatic attribute `node['fqdn']`](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#automatic-ohai):

```
...
Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d
Hostname=<%= node['fqdn'] %>
```

In case you really want only the host name without the domain name attached, there's `node['hostname']`.

You probably know that there are a couple of Zabbix cookbooks available in the [Chef supermarket](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=zabbix&platforms%5B%5D=).

Comment: when i add this attribute "Hostname=<%= node['fqdn'] %>" in my recipe and run the chef-client i get this below error. 
                                                 
[2017-07-01T06:53:35+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-07-01T06:53:35+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-07-01T06:53:35+00:00] ERROR: /root/mytest/recipes/default.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

Comment: Please edit your question and add your current template. Can't see where the syntax error is in this case.